# cvxpy import error : cannot read file data

Tags: python, flask, scipy, virtualenv, cvxpy

I'm trying to use cvxpy on a pythonanywhere server, the installation was ok, no errors however when i want to import cvpxy as cp, i have an error, help me please
the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/padacore/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cvxpy/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from cvxpy.atoms import *
  File "/home/padacore/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cvxpy/atoms/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from cvxpy.atoms.cummax import cummax
  File "/home/padacore/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cvxpy/atoms/cummax.py", line 17, in <module>
    from cvxpy.atoms.atom import Atom
  File "/home/padacore/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cvxpy/atoms/atom.py", line 21, in <module>
    from cvxpy.expressions.constants import Constant
  File "/home/padacore/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cvxpy/expressions/constants/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .constant import Constant
  File "/home/padacore/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cvxpy/expressions/constants/constant.py", line 22, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigsh
  File "/home/padacore/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/__init__.py", line 111, in <module>
    from .isolve import *
  File "/home/padacore/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .iterative import *
  File "/home/padacore/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/iterative.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import _iterative
ImportError: /home/padacore/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/../../../../scipy.libs/libopenblasp-r0-085ca80a.3.9.so: cannot read file data
```

Comment: I tired to reproduce your problem by running (on PythonAnyhwere):

`$ mkvirtualenv cvxpy -p python3.7`
`$ pip install cvxpy`
`$ python`
`>>> import cvpxy as cp`

It worked fine, without any problem.
How was your `cvxpy` installed? Did you make any other changes to your venv?

Comment: I finally found the problem, it was an issue with scipy installation, i just reinstalled it and it works ! thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

It could be something to do with Atom, try switching to another editor. I recommend PyCharm or VSCode. If you're choosing VSCode, install these extensions: Python, PyLance, and Jupyter.

If you don't like VSCode's default themes, and miss Atom's One Dark, then there's an extension just for that! Just search for it, and you'll find it!

EDIT: If it wasn't something to do with Atom, maybe install an older version of cvxpy

Comment: Okey thank you ! i'm doing it in a server online so it's all on command line there is no editor, but i will try to install an older version